# Issue in execution of event synthesis code for continuous integration for speech translation

Tags: python, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, speech

```
from_language = 'fr-FR'
to_language = 'en-US'

def synthesis_callback(evt):
    size = len(evt.result.audio)
    print(f'Audio synthesized: {size} byte(s) {"(COMPLETED)" if size == 0 else ""}')

    if size > 0:
        file = open('translation.wav', 'wb+')
        file.write(evt.result.audio)
        file.close()

def translate_speech_to_text():

    translation_config = speechsdk.translation.SpeechTranslationConfig(
            subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    translation_config.speech_recognition_language = from_language
    translation_config.add_target_language(to_language)

    translation_config.voice_name = "en-US-JennyNeural"
    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename=filename)

    recognizer = speechsdk.translation.TranslationRecognizer(translation_config=translation_config, audio_config = audio_input )

    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that stops continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    # Start continuous speech recognition
    recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)
     
translate_speech_to_text()
```

> Issue: I'm trying to execute python code for event synthesis speech
> translation from Azure Cognitive Speech services documentation. I have
> added code from github samples for callbacks to the events for
> continuous integration. Although translation starts, it gets cancelled
> after first utterance. Can someone help resolve this issue?

Log after commenting below line:

```
recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))


SESSION STARTED: SessionEventArgs(session_id=6e378e05c98249c3be3aa702fd686270)
RECOGNIZING: TranslationRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=6e378e05c98249c3be3aa702fd686270, result=TranslationRecognitionResult(result_id=e50145c39bfc463cb6284f96332a822b, translations={'en': 'Paul'}, reason=ResultReason.TranslatingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: TranslationRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=6e378e05c98249c3be3aa702fd686270, result=TranslationRecognitionResult(result_id=ba62d3981efa418e909d6923de01a5bb, translations={'en': 'Paul Verlaine'}, reason=ResultReason.TranslatingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: TranslationRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=6e378e05c98249c3be3aa702fd686270, result=TranslationRecognitionResult(result_id=82b2b61a950a42a096a76fd8d50ab2b3, translations={'en': 'Paul Verlaine, autumn song'}, reason=ResultReason.TranslatingSpeech))
RECOGNIZED: TranslationRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=6e378e05c98249c3be3aa702fd686270, result=TranslationRecognitionResult(result_id=65db6b16dbe443e9a6144c112d634b30, translations={'en': 'Paul Verlaine, autumn song.'}, reason=ResultReason.TranslatedSpeech))
CLOSING on TranslationRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=6e378e05c98249c3be3aa702fd686270, result=TranslationRecognitionResult(result_id=29fb7547f33a4a4d968ebeae997c84a8, translations={}, reason=ResultReason.Canceled))
```

Comment: Why do define event `recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)` twice?

Comment: Thanks. I have now commented the first one i.e. 
 #recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt))). Now I am getting following log but its not reading entire audio. Also, I tried to change function to start_continuous_recognition_async()

Comment: Pasted log in the question due to space issues.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can add a line in canceled event callback to print the cancellation details

```py
recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}, error_detail={}'.format(evt, evt.result.cancellation_details.error_details)))
```

In your case, the error detail is `Synthesis service failed with code:  - Could not identify the voice 'en-US-JennyNeural' for the text to speech service`. For speech-to-speech translation, neural voices are not supported for now. You can refer to `Manual synthesis` section of this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-translation?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-python) to synthesize the translated text.